Cooling properties of trees and thermal radiation
A question about trees, shading and thermal radiation: Will the shaded area under trees have lower average air temperature than adjacent non-shaded areas?
On the one hand, I've read that the real air temperature inside and outside shade is the same, and just the perceived temperature is different (see, for instance, this article).
On the other hand, there's lots of literature on the cooling benefits of trees. I would think the ground materials in the shade absorb less shortwave radiation, and therefore emit less longwave/thermal radiation. That should make the area in the shade cooler than in the sun. Thanks.

Well, you aren’t getting heated by direct sun. And water evaporation from the leaves keeps it cooler near the tree.

Note that trees have the opposite effect in winter - the ground and air temperature are warmer near trees in cold weather.

One needs to distinguish between real temperature and percieved temperature. The temperature we feel can be very different from the actual temperature of the surrounding air depending on factors such as wind chill, humidity, sunlight intensity etc. If convection is possible in much shorter times than the observation time of a system, shaded and lit areas will have the same real air temperature because the warmer air from the sunlit area mixes with the cooler air in the shaded area and brings the system into thermal equilibrium. Of course, in the sun, it will feel hotter because of the thermal radiation recieved from the sun and also the surrounding objects.
The cooling benefits of trees go beyond simple shading. A large portion of their cooling effect comes from water evaporating from their leaves, which takes energy and therefore cools the surrounding air. Also, water has a rather high heat capacity, so the humid air warms up slower. Now, a single tree surrounded by concrete won't have much of an effect because of convection as described above, but multiple trees surrounded by grass and soil will definetely create a noticeable drop in air temperature as well as felt temperature. The extreme example would be a dense forest, where the foliage provides shading and water evaporating from leaves and the moist soil cools the air. Further, the dense tree growth will inhibit movement of air, reducing air convection and making sure that the cool air remains within the forest.The convection that does happen is in turn felt as wind, which reduces the felt temperature further.

The question you asked, about the difference in temperature between shady and sunny areas, is not the same as the question of whether trees have cooling benefits.
Planting trees may cool the air. However, that cooling is not localized to the shade of one tree. Air moves and mixes quite easily, and on human-sized scales like a single backyard, it is reasonable to assume that the air is approximately fully mixed. Thus, the air temperature is approximately the same in your whole backyard, whether you are in the sun or the shade.
The tree still makes the air cooler than it would otherwise be, especially if it is preventing the sun from striking highly absorptive surfaces like asphalt. But the cooling is spread out over a much larger area than its own shade.
On a much larger scale -- for example, a weather front producing a massive area of clouds that shade the ground -- the approximation of full mixing is no longer reasonable, and a significant temperature difference can be produced between the shady and sunny areas.

Excellent answer, thanks very much -- this is exactly what I was trying to understand.
